# How to design a class to check if geometric figures collide?

Tags: object-oriented-design, class-design

I am making a basic game with geometric figures.

I am trying to design now how to calculate if the figure collides with another figure in an Array List of figures (called `entitiesList`).

I have:

```
Class Entity {
   ...
   public boolean collidesWith(Entity anotherEntityInMap) {}
}
```

But I can't figure out how I  should make this. I guess I must know what kind of figure is `anotherEntity`. For example, I can have squares, triangles and circles. Each figure has diverse calculations, and it must be abstracted.

Comment: If you don't need a *precise* collision, the easiest way is to use a "fat point;" i.e. draw a circle around the center of the object that corresponds roughly to the outer edge.  You can then compare the location of the circle perimeters to detect collisions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey since I am making them going in a grid (same Y position, 6 different positions), maybe I can use the `PosX + Entity.Width / 2` to know if the other entity is in the same  `x` set ?

Comment: Something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most academically proper way of doing it would be to have a two-dimensional matrix of collision detection methods, one method for each possible pair of figures, so each method would have knowledge of precisely what figures are being checked, so as to do the checking in the best way possible.  Unfortunately, this is too much work for very little benefit.

The quickest, dirtiest, simplest, hackiest and most inaccurate way of doing it would be to treat all shapes equally, consider them all to be circles, and just check the distance between their centerpoints to determine if they collide.

A practical solution which is not too difficult to implement and yields accurate results is to have each shape contain a polygon representation of itself, and simply make use of a single polygon collision detection algorithm to detect collision between the polygon representations of any two shapes.

Comment: +1 for polygon if applicable, was about to post that myself.

Comment: I made them all be rectangles by now, so I check if the square is inside the other square with the axis

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you can wrap some common logic in all shapes.

   1. Try to see if objects collide according to their [AABB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box#Axis-aligned_minimum_bounding_box); all shapes implement `getAABB()`.
   2. You may also call `getBoundingBox()` or `getBoundingSphere()` before trying to check if they really intersect.
2. The above should allow you to quickly filter all shapes that certainly do *not* collide (your bounding boxes are over-approximations of your shapes). But if there remain entities for which over-approximations overlap, you cannot be sure that they do *not* collide and you have to be more precise. You may implement douple-dispatch:

   - Typically, this is done using a [Visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762256/how-does-double-dispatch-work-in-visitor-pattern).
   - Each shape, `Rectangle`, `Circle` implements `collideWithRectangle`, `collideWithCircle`, and so on...
   - You want to avoid repeating yourself, so if you implement a test for `Rectangle` against `Circle`, you can reverse the arguments when checking for collision between a `Circle` and a `Rectangle` and call the existing method.
   - Complex entities are most of the time easily represented by a union of simpler shapes, but you can also use arbitrary polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Harvey's comment about emitting a circle from the center to approximate the shape was good.  You can alternatively use rectangles/triangles on a 2D surface, such as in your game, or a rectangular prism / some triangular equivalent in a 3D environment.  You may also divide each of your shapes into a collection of these smaller shapes to approximate the actual shape on a finer scale (using elliptical or straight-edged shapes), and this is basically how a lot of CPU-heavy games run as efficiently as they do.

That being said, you could make all these objects extend the same base class.  Then in that class, there would be an overridable method/property called `getCollisionComponentShapes`, which would return an array or `ArrayList` of the shapes.  This would be the elliptical shapes, rectangles, and/or triangles mentioned earlier that would be used to approximate the polygon.  That reduces everything to, let's say, three functions, assuming you just stick with straight-edged shapes:

```
detectCollisionReRe(pRect1:Rectangle, pRect2:Rectangle):Boolean
detectCollisionReTr(pRect1:Rectangle, pTri2:Triangle):Boolean
detectCollisionTrTr(pTri1:Triangle, pTri2:Triangle):Boolean
```

Then in your base class, there would be a presumably static method:

```
detectCollisionShapes(pBaseClassRef1:BaseClass, pBaseClassRef2:BaseClass):Boolean
```

and this would just run through the collision shapes of each instance and run one of the three functions above for each combination.

This would be one big way to handle the general case.  In your geometry game, I would advise going ahead and using some sort of generic ellipse shape with variable curvature for your components, in addition to rectangles and triangles.  Even with variable curvature, you can use sophomore-level math, and that'll only bring the list up to six functions.

As a side note, you probably wouldn't need this in your game, but if you were designing a AAA game, it might be good to look for ways to cache results and cut corners in other ways.